# Touchpad not working on Acer Aspire One Cloudbook 11

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad, acer

I can't seem to get the touchpad to work on 14.04 on my Acer Aspire One Cloudbook 11.

A USB mouse works fine. I have 14.04 on a separate partition from Windows 10. I have updated all packages using `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

I've also tried the many suggestions I've found from searches, including:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

and

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Neither seem to do anything. The touchpad has a toggle via <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, but the toggle doesn't seem to affect anything. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>... works for muting and volume and other keys though.

Distro: 14.04 LTS
Kernel: 3.19.0-30-generic

Comment: Changing Touchpad to Basic in BioS appears to fix this! As per this suggestion: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1487748/comments/2 Cursor movement, left click, right click, and two finger scrolling seems to work! About everything I can think I'd need. Seems solved.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your BIOS settings to verify it is not running in **Advanced** mode.  If it is, set it to **Basic**.

The problem was solved in my case after making that setting change. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and try again if it still does not work in case the soft switch is set to off.